# In the ECS on my server, how should I organize components along with systems?

Tags: java, client-server, server, entity-component-system

A quick note about my server is that it executes game logic in 250ms intervals.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to do this. The main issue I have is currently that I have the map of entityIds and components of each component type inside its respective system. I don't know if that is the best solution because then I end up with things like a transform system which isn't really going to do anything from what I reason so farconsidering I already have a movement system that updates transforms anyway. The only thing it would be used for is a way to get a reference to a transform component in whatever system needs to access it and maybe just send transform data to the client when it changes every tick.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: It's unclear to me what specific problem you need help solving here. Is having a system that exists as a means to index a set of components a bad thing? Has it created any obstacles for your development team, or shown up as a significant bottleneck in your profiling? What should answers aim to make "better" about your current approach?

Comment: Hmm it has not really caused any problems no. Something about it just bothered me. I suppose it shouldn't really matter where the components are held. Maybe when I have more components it might become an issue but I guess I'll see.